# Convert normalization from Pandas to AWK to improve performance

Tags: python, pandas, awk

I have a single cell RNA-sequencing dataset which I want to normalize, however due to it's size (>1,000,000 cells, ~23,000 genes) using Python with Pandas is simply not efficient enough (even when optimizing data types, partitioning data and 128GB of RAM at my disposal).

Therefore, I want to run this normalization step in AWK (or other methods that would be useful), skipping the memory-intensive Pandas approach. Conceptually, the dataset is a TSV file with genes as rows and cells as columns. The size is ~130GB, when testing on a subset of ~1GB it would require ~6GB of RAM in Pandas. It is not feasible to run normalization on the entire dataset, yet normalizing let's say 100 partitions is still a very ineffective method.

This is an example (with example data) of how normalization should proceed, which I have successfully applied on smaller subsets:

```
# determine dtypes and downcast to reduce memory usage
tmp_count_data = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep="\t", index_col=0, nrows=100)
tmp_float_cols = [c for c in tmp_count_data if tmp_count_data[c].dtype == "float64"]
tmp_float32_cols = {c: np.float32 for c in tmp_float_cols}

count_data = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep="\t", index_col=0, engine="c", dtype=tmp_float32_cols)

>>> count_data
       c1   c2
-              
GeneA  0.0  0.0
GeneB  1.0  0.0
GeneC  6.0  3.0
GeneD  4.0  3.0


def normalize(df):
    # load dataframe values
    dge = df.values
    # calculate column sums
    col_sums = np.apply_along_axis(sum,0,dge)
    # divide cell value by column sum, multiply by 10000, add 1, apply natural logarithm
    mat_dge_norm = np.log( dge/[float(x) for x in col_sums] * 10000 + 1 ) 
    # add column and row names back to dataframe
    df_dge_norm = pd.DataFrame(mat_dge_norm,index=df.index,columns=df.columns)
    # return dataframe
    return df_dge_norm
```

Normalization should go as follows:

- divide cell k in column C by the sum of column C
- divide this by 10000
- add 1 to this
- take the natural logarithm of the result

Comment: if it's 130GB it might be time to go with a big data approach, i.e Spark, which should have no problem handling this across several nodes

Answer (score 2):

doing this with `awk` is almost trivial, doesn't require much memory but needs to scan the file twice

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {c1+=$2; c2+=$3; next} 
               {print $1, log($2/(c1*1000)+1), log($3/(c2*1000)+1)}' file{,}

GeneA 0 0
GeneB 9.0905e-05 0
GeneC 0.000545306 0.000499875
GeneD 0.00036357 0.000499875
```

you can format numbers as well, but not sure it's needed.

If the timing is not reasonable, you can split the file, compute sums of chunks add them up, then divide chunks with the grand totals, again the memory won't be the issue but the number of processes you can run concurrently, assuming P processes, you can reduce the time almost proportionally.